# Find loops in graph

Tags: plsql

I have a graph which is described as edges in a database.

Can anybody share an idea how **to identify loops in the graph**?

Like I have in the example the loop among nodes 3, 4 and 5.

**P.S.**

I'm solving this problem in Oracle.

[image]

Comment: Generally a depth first search is done. Basically if you have a route back to any traversed node, then it contains a loop. There should be algorithms available online